# Google sheet checkbox

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am sharing the sheet with you . The sheet i am sharing is not the sheet from my company , this is the sample sheet . The same function we will do in main sheet .
In sheet 1 there is check-boxes and names and age .
In sheet 2 there is name and age as heading .
If i am checking the first checkbox which is A2 then i can not check other check-boxes and the data in B2 and C3 will be showing in sheet2 (A2 & B2 ).
If i am checking the checkbox A4 then the  name and age which is there in the corresponding column i.e "Z & 47" should be shown in sheet2 (A2 & B2).
 file link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQo0xSmZqVNqKLLXJwOXAL1bknryfxgqEk-KCBaZx1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you please summarise your research for this question.

Answer (score 1):

try simply:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:C, Sheet1!A2:A=TRUE), "(no data)")
```

[image: 0]